# Android Tablet and Mobile layout issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I am facing big problem, when I run the application in phones it is working perfectly resources are displaying properly, but when I run the application in 7 inch and 10 inch android tablets it is crashing.

I am having following folders

```
drawable
drawable-hdpi
drawable-large
drawable-large-hdpi
drawable-large-mdpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-xlarge
drawable-xlarge-mdpi
layout
layout-large
layout-small
layout-sw600dp
layout-sw720dp
layout-xlarge
```

I want to know what mistake I am doing, I am getting the following and app crashes

04-22 08:27:20.786: E/AndroidRuntime(1344): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.canada/com.test.canada.WelcomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout

There is nothing special in the XML, it is just a simple one

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/splash"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:background="@drawable/splash"
>    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think the layout for 7 inch will be different than the layout for a 10 inch. Hence there are two different related snippets of code, please update with all the four you have used.

Comment: problem is your layout is different for phone and tablet..compare your phone layout with layout-xlarge or layout-sw720dp.

Comment: this is from layout-sw600dp

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/splash"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/splash"
    >
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: In all the layouts I am using the same XML but its is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can follow http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html.It will be solution of all device support issue. also you can follow http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html and http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html . Best of Luck!